# Products in Category not showing all products in the category back-end

Tags: catalog, backend, magento2.3.4

Not all products show under "Products in Category" when editing a category in the back-end.

Here is a screenshot showing the problem.  In the category tree, it correctly shows 123 products in 'Commercial' category.  But under the products section, only 9 appear (see bottom right).

[image: Product tree / visible products count mismatch]

Other categories are fine and show the same number of products in the tree and in the products list.

I've run the reindexer from the command line and this didn't help.  For info, both 'Use Flat Catalog Category' and 'Use Flat Catalog Product' are set to Yes.

Magento version 2.3.4

PHP 7.3.16

Mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB

Thanks.

Comment: Your above image showing click reset filter link and after check

Comment: I did try.  Reset filter just removes the category filter, after which, all products show.

Comment: i don't understand your comment .Please explain me

Comment: You're saying I should click the "Reset Filter" link.  I did that and afterwards, all products in the store show.  In other words, clicking the link just removes the filter for the category.

Answer (score 0):

I found this similar question which points towards an answer: [Magento 2 : Admin category products getting wrong count](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261068/magento-2-admin-category-products-getting-wrong-count)

Confusingly, the tree shows the products in the category, plus in all its subcategories (if Anchor is set to Yes in the Display Settings section).  However, the Products in Category section only shows products in that particular category, and does not include child categories.

So the above image is actually correct since there are only 9 products in the Commercial category itself, with the rest in sub-categories.